# How to globally disable notification prompt in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Almost every website bugs you to allow them to show notifications in Chrome. Some keep on asking every time you visit the page even after selecting 'No'. Some are even more clever and just show a big 'Enable' button with a little x hidden somewhere.

How to stop this globally?

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can’t, because those are not Chrome dialogs. They’re specific to every website and displayed “inside” the website.

Answer (score 1):

1. In Chrome go to **Settings**
2. Select **Show Advanced Settings**
3. Under **Privacy** click on **Content Settings**
4. Scroll down to **Notifications** and select the **Do not allow any site to show notification** radio button
5. With most Chrome settings they take effect right away but I've found with this particular setting I've had to close Chrome and reopen it to make sure it takes effect

[image]

Comment: Yes but this setting doesn't prevent these dialogs from appearing.

Comment: This setting also doesn't appear to exist anymore.

Comment: Option for "Do not allow any site to show notification" removed from later versions of Chrome.